# inline function promt a unique value

Tags: matlab

i have run several test on my plot but here is the bug:
i have an inline function phi(x):
for x=0 phi(x)=0
for x=2.61 phi(x)=2.61

when i plot phi(x), all value equals 2.45, i don't know why it does this on this particular function.

here is the part of the code which is bugged

```
phi=inline('(3*x.^2)/(1+x.^2)','x');
x=[-1:0.01:3];
figure; plot(x,phi(x),'g')
hold on; plot(x,x,'r')
grid on
```

Test done with matlab

> > phi

phi =

```
 Inline function:
 phi(x) = (3*x.^2)/(1+x.^2)
```

> > phi(x)

ans =

```
      2.44184657385039
```

> > size(x)

ans =

```
 1   401
```

> > phi(0)

ans =

```
 0
```

> > phi(2.61)

ans =

```
      2.61598033819332
```

the think is i don't know why matlab think phi(x) is a variable equals to 2.45

---

full code:

```
clear all
close all
clc

f=inline('x.^3-3*x.^2+x','x');
g=inline('0','x');
x=[-1:0.01:3];
figure; plot(x,f(x),x,g(x),'r')
grid on

format long g  
phi=inline('(3*x.^2)/(1+x.^2)','x');
x=[-1:0.01:3];
figure; plot(x,phi(x),'g')
hold on; plot(x,x,'r') % afichage de y=x pour voir le point fixe
grid on
```

Comment: Moreover, I have tried to change the name of the function phi with one letter, of the vector with a different name but still it won't work...

Comment: You need to use `./` rather than `/`

Comment: thank you, i will remember this for my exam tomorrow!